# How to make scroll animation work when you scroll both ways (down AND up)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a small animation on my web page which is triggered using .scroll() function.

My .js script is:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

var s = $(document).scrollTop();

if(s >= 2400)

{
$("#top").animate({
"top":"820px",
"left":"0"
},'linear');
}
```

})

It works when I scroll down, but I would like element with id #top to get back to it's original position after I scroll back up. Any help would be appreciated :)

CSS:

```
#top{   
height:200px;
width:200px;
display:block;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
top: 860px;
position:relative; 
}
```

Comment: Before asking any questions here please take a [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of *SO* and study [**how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question simply states that you haven't done anything at your end.

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function(){ your code goes here });`

Comment: Oh. This is, obviously, my first post here.. :)

The thing is, I really don't know what to add. I don't have any .js code I can post, I was just looking for some script I could examine and learn from. I saw some answers that got removed which might be just the read I need :)

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work, but now I'd like it to do the opposite thing on scroll up - to go back to it's place. Codes posted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it. Sort of.

```
var line = 2500;
var isMyHeadOpen = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
var s = $(document).scrollTop();

if(s >= line && !isMyHeadOpen) {
    isMyHeadOpen = true;
    $("#top").animate({
    "top":"840px",
    "left":"0"
    },'linear');
} else if (s < line && isMyHeadOpen) {
    isMyHeadOpen = false;
    $("#top").animate({
    "top":"880px",
    "left":"0"
    },'linear');
}
})
```

When I scroll to line 2500, animation triggers. When I scroll back, animation moves back to original place. The thing is variable line depends on monitor resolution so it should somehow be dynamic and I have no idea how to fix that.